# Find the Laurent expansion $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z)^2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent Series expansion of

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z)^2}$$

at $z=1$.

How do I do this when I am not given any region?

Comment: The region is implicitly given to you since the center is given to you. What is the largest region be if the center is $z=1$?

Comment: @Clayton $|z-1|\gt 0$?

Comment: Since there is a pole at $z=0$, it will actually be $0<|z-1|<1$ (the distance from $1$ to the nearest pole is $1$).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z)^2}=\frac{1}{1-(1-z)}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(1-z)^2}\\=\dfrac{1}{(z-1)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(z-1)^n$$

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a region. The function is defined in a pointed neighbourhood of $1$, that is all you need. 
If it helps, shift the function so that the pole is at $0$: $f(1+z)=g(z)$, then the shifted function is $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(1+z)}$. The Laurent expansion of this function is $\sum\limits_{n=-2}^{\infty} (-1)^n z^n$, as you can easily obtain from the power series of $\frac{1}{1+z}$.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: This makes sense. May be a stupid question but we were taught to use the standard and modified geometric series for $|z|\lt 1$ and $|z|\gt 1$. How do you know which to choose in this case?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the second option. I used the standard one, with $|z|<1$. The closest pole to $1$ is $0$, so the convergence radius is $1$, you need to use a formula that works for $|z|<1$. (I understand your comment now.)